# Basic T-SQL Pass variable to LEFT

Tags: sql-server

this seems really basic, but why does this not work?

```
DECLARE @Test1 INT
DECLARE @Test2 NVARCHAR
SELECT @Test1 = CHARINDEX('_', 'x1Left_r2Right')-1
SELECT @Test2 = LEFT('x1Left_r2Right', @Test1)
PRINT @Test1
PRINT @Test2
```

if your following my logic, the result should be 'x1Left', however it seems `@Test` always evalutes to 1 in the second select even though it contains a 6.

This is the current output:

```
6
x
```

i'm on sql-server 2014.

Comment: Yep, you know I just figured it out.  NVARCHAR is returning 1 character if i don't specify the length.  When did that come into play?

Comment: the `LEFT()` it is fine. It does returns the `x1Left`. But when assigning to @Test2, which is only 1 character in size, it got truncated

Comment: Haha I just noticed the width wasn't explicitly given. I have always declared length so I don't know what the default does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you declared `@Test2` as `NVARCHAR` without the size. By default that is size of 1. That's why you get `x` the first character only

change to `NVARCHAR(100)` and it will be ok

Comment: So dumb on my part.  Thanks.